# How to Add '/' in Primeng Calendar Datepicker for manual inputs

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to add slashes inside manual input using primeng Calendar.

```
<p-calendar
   [monthNavigator]="true"
   [yearNavigator]="true"
   yearRange="1950:2021"
   ngModel
   [required]="true" 
   [maxDate]='today'
   [showOnFocus]="false"
   id="date1"
   [showIcon]="true"
   name="date1"
   inputId="date1"
   placeholder="Date Of Birth">
</p-calendar>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding slashes". If you mean display the date using slashes (e.g. 2/14/2021), you could check out the `dateFormat` attribute. Or edit the post to add an example of what the situation is now and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @OlliM this seems it should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

Slashes are already supported in PrimeNG calendar.

If it is not working for you, maybe you have set the calendar date format to something without slashes. You can explicitly set the format here as well

```
<p-calendar 
  [monthNavigator]="true" 
  [yearNavigator]="true" 
  yearRange="1950:2021" 
  ngModel  
  [required]="true" 
  [maxDate]='today' 
  [showOnFocus]="false" 
  id="date1" 
  [showIcon]="true"  
  name="date1" 
  inputId="date1" 
  placeholder="Date Of Birth" 
  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy">
</p-calendar>
```

-- **Edit** --

If you are looking for date mask in PrimeNG calendar, it is not yet supported. This [request](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1426) is open as of Feb 2020.

You can one of the date mask libraries. I used [racoon-mask](https://github.com/shogogan/racoon-mask) for my Angular 7 repository. You can use it as follows -

```
npm install --save racoon-mask
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import {PrimeNgCalendarMaskModule} from 'racoon-mask'
...
...
imports:      [ ..., CalendarModule, PrimeNgCalendarMaskModule ]
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p-calendar 
  [monthNavigator]="true" 
  [yearNavigator]="true" 
  yearRange="1950:2021" 
  ngModel  
  [required]="true" 
  [maxDate]='today' 
  [showOnFocus]="false" 
  id="date1" 
  name="date1" 
  inputId="date1" 
  placeholder="Date Of Birth" 
  dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"
  rPCalendarMask>
</p-calendar>
<p>
```

Comment: I want to add / automatically when someone enters date manually

Comment: I think what you are looking for is date masking. I've edited my answer to show how to use a date masking lib with PrimeNg calendar. See if this helps.